# how add a picture event when selected by dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html

These is my HTML code:

```
<select>
<option>Pic1</option>
<option>Pic2</option>
<option>Pic3/option>
<option>Pic4</option>
</select>
```

Sorry for my code,
i am just mostly learning at shcool

I want to make a event that add a picture while a option tag is selected in 75% of witdh and centered in screen

I have not been learn all about javascript, soo sorry

Comment: Have you learnt any js? It may be worth spending a little time understanding the basics  and then coming back if you run into errors.

Comment: You should first search and try to solve the issue, provide us with what you've tried so far and what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery and change image on the change event , 
I've used data attribute to get image urls :

see below snippet

```js
$(function(){
  $("#select-pic").on("change",function(e){
     var url = $(this).find(':selected').data('pic-url');
     
     if(url) {
        $("#picture").attr('src',url);
     }
     else {
        $("#picture").attr("src", "");
     }
  })
  
});
```

```css
#picture {
  width:70%;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  margin:auto;
}

.container {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-pic">
  <option></option>
  <option data-pic-url='https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e85d00/6b7de0.png&text=+picture1' >Pic1</option>
  <option data-pic-url='https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e85d00/6b7de0.png&text=+picture2' >Pic2</option>
  <option data-pic-url='https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e85d00/6b7de0.png&text=+picture3' >Pic3</option>
  <option data-pic-url='https://dummyimage.com/500x200/e85d00/6b7de0.png&text=+picture4' >Pic4</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
  <img id="picture" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP asked for the images to be _"75% of witdh and centered in screen"_

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```js
var pictures = {
    "Pic1": "http://via.placeholder.com/500x200/9575cd/ffffff",
    "Pic2": "http://via.placeholder.com/500x200/64b5f6/ffffff",
    "Pic3": "http://via.placeholder.com/500x200/4db6ac/ffffff",
    "Pic4": "http://via.placeholder.com/500x200/ffb74d/ffffff",
};

var container = $("#image-container");
$("select").on("change", function (event) {
    var element = $("option:selected", this),
      value = element.text(),
      image = pictures[value] || null,
      imageElement = $("#image-container > img");

    if (image !== null) {
        imageElement.show();
        
        // don' change anything if the image is not defined.
        if (imageElement.length > 0) {
            imageElement.attr("src", image);
        } else {
            container.append('<img src="' + image + '" alt="wide image" />')
        }
    } else {
        imageElement.hide();
    }
});
```

```css
#image-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#image-container > img {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option selected disabled>Choose an image</option>
    <option>Pic1</option>
    <option>Pic2</option>
    <option>Pic3</option>
    <option>Pic4</option>
    <option>Pic5</option>
</select>

<div id="image-container"></div>
```

It basically defines an object with all option-texts from your select and the correlating image path, listenes on every change in the select menu and shows or hides the image depending on the selected object. We're using CSS to center and stretch and center the image.

If there is an option text which is not defined in the `pictures` object the image element gets hidden and not shown until the selected options text exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         function AddImage(){
          var pathImg = $("#mySelect option:selected").val();
          var htmImg = "<img src='"+ pathImg +"'>";
          $("#destiny").html(htmImg);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <select id="mySelect" onchange="AddImage()">
         <option></option>
         <option value="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/01/06/19/15/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg">pic1</option>
         <option value="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg">pic2</option>
         <option value="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg">pic3</option>
      </select>
      <div id="destiny" style="width:75%; text-align: center;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```